# Difficulty with writing a merge function with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

Im trying to write a function but simply cant get it right. This is supposed to be a merge function the merges as follows: the function recieves as an input a list of lists(m lists, all ints). The function creates a list that contains the indexes of the minimun values in each list of the input(each list of the list of lists, overall m indexes). example: 
 lst_of_lsts= [[3,4,5],[2,0,7]]
 min_lst= [0,1]

At each stage, the function chooses the minimum value from that list and adds it to a new list called merged. Then, it erases it from the list of indexes(min_lst) and adds the next index which is now the new minimum.
At the end it returns merged which is an organized list from small ints to big ints. example:
merged= [0,2,3,4,5,7]

Another thing is that Im not allowed to change the original input.

Answer (score 1):

```
def min_index(lst):
    return min(range(len(lst)), key=lambda n: lst[n])

def min_lists(lstlst):
    return [min_index(lst) for lst in lstlst]
```

then

```
min_lists([[3,4,5],[2,0,7]])   # => [0, 1]
```

**Edit:**

This site doesn't exist to solve your homework for you. If you work at it and your solution doesn't do what you expect, show us what you've done and we'll try to point out your mistake.

I figure my solution is OK because it's correct, but in such a way that your teacher will never believe you wrote it; however if you can understand this solution it should help you solve it yourself, and along the way teach you some Python-fu.